# Add inline style to Table TR tag, not working

Tags: html, css

It's late and I've been up all day... SO, forgive me if this is a ridiculous question...

Why is this not working???

```
<tr style="font-size: 1em;">
```

Is my brain so fried that I forgot you can't style a TR with font size?

Comment: Apply inline style for <td> tag

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with your code snippet. Which browser are you using to view files?

Comment: 1em is equals to 16 pixels. If your default font size is 16px, then you definitely won't see a change. Just test it as 2em and see if the font size became bigger. I just checked and it did, so your code is actually working.

Comment: still it will not going to work he need to set font size to td not tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set font-size to `<td>` because `font-size` does not go in the tr tag. check this link:

[style attribute to TR and TD](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/53a473a552f863a0f3000b31)

Comment: This is not a link only answer, as it actually has a suggestion of what has to be done and the link is for a reference. It is another story, that a code example will increase the value of the answer.